# Cannot connect my Windows laptop with BLE adapter to BLE device

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, anki

I am trying to set up a demo based on **Nodejs** on my **Windows** laptop with an extra **BLE** adapter to connect my laptop to another **BLE** device (**Anki Overdrive**). I have seen this demo on the internet and was curious, if I could set it up, too. I have followed all the instructions, but failed, because the original demo was made with a **MacBook** which is using a different kind of build-in **BLE** adapter. I tried it with a **MacBook**, too, and it worked more than fine, but I'd like to set it up with a **Windows** device. I attached a part of the **Nodejs** code which should return the peripheral ID of the **BLE** device:

```
//UUID for Anki Overdrive Car be15beef6186407e83810bd89c4d8df4

var noble = require('noble');

noble.on('stateChange', function(state) {
  if (state === 'poweredOn') {
    noble.startScanning();

    setTimeout(function() {
       noble.stopScanning();
       process.exit(0);
     }, 2000);
  } else {
    noble.stopScanning();
  }
});

noble.on('discover', function(peripheral) {
  var serviceUuids = JSON.stringify(peripheral.advertisement.serviceUuids);
  if(serviceUuids.indexOf("be15beef6186407e83810bd89c4d8df4") > -1) {
    console.log('Car discovered. ID: ' + peripheral.id); 
  }
});
```

What I figured out so far is that the built-in **BLE** from the **MacBook** sends back the peripheral ID. In comparison, the **Windows** **BLE** Adapter only returns the MAC address from the other **BLE** device. Can anyone help me? I have really no idea what I could do to solve the problem.

For further understanding, I have provided the link to the original demo which was set up with a **MacBook**. https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/node-mqtt-for-anki-overdrive.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens on the Windows device?  Do you see anything in the console e.g. "Car discovered.  ID: XXX"?  You might try increasing the 2000 timeout to something longer to give the Windows adapter more time to discover the device.

Comment: @davidgyoung I receive an console output, but instead of the real peripheral ID as it is done by the MacBook, the MAC address is returned (even it says "Car discovered ID: XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX"). Normally, I should receive a 32 bit string. But anyway, I try your solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, so it detects it just fine.  Good news -- no need to increase the timeout. From the code shown, everything looks ok.  You need to show more code, at least the part that does something with the returned identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the Anki Overdrive cars always is a hassle.

The following snippets show the relevant code regarding you question.

Disclaimer: I created a WIP Anki Overdrive SDK [1] that tries to make life easier (The snippets are copied from there)

1. **Scan for devices using noble (scanner.js)**

```
module.exports = class Scanner {
    constructor() {
        this.peripherals = []
        this.state = undefined
    }

/**
 * Set up noble listeners. Mandatory before scan.
 */
async setUpNoble () {
    try {
        await noble.on('discover', (peripheral) => {
            const isAnkiDevice = function(peripheral) {
                const serviceUuids = JSON.stringify(peripheral.advertisement.serviceUuids)
                return (serviceUuids.indexOf("be15beef6186407e83810bd89c4d8df4") > -1)
            }

            if(isAnkiDevice(peripheral)) {
                this.peripherals.push(peripheral)
            }
        })
        await noble.on('stateChange', (status) => {
            this.state = status
        })
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}

/**
 * Scans for devices and returns peripherals. Scans for 20 seconds before stopping.
 */
async scan() {
    try {
        let that = this
        await waitUntil(() => {
            return (that.state === 'poweredOn')
        }, 20000)
        console.log('Starting to scan...')
        return await waitUntil(() => {
            noble.stopScanning()
            if(that.peripherals.length <= 0) {
                console.log('Scanning...')
                noble.startScanning()
            } else {
                console.log('Found ' + that.peripherals.length + ' devices.')
                return that.peripherals
            }
        }, 20000, 4000)
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
}
```

2. **Trigger scan and create device object (anki.js)**

```
async scanDevices() {
    try {
        const that = this
        const scanner = new Scanner()
        scanner.setUpNoble()

        const peripherals = await scanner.scan()  
        const devices = peripherals.map((peripheral) => {
            return new Device(peripheral)
        })

        return devices
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }

}
```

3. **Set id and serviceUUids from peripheral in constructor of Device object (device.js)**

```
module.exports = class AnkiDevice {
    constructor (peripheral) {
        this.peripheral = peripheral
        this.id = peripheral.uuid
        this.serviceUuids = JSON.stringify(peripheral.advertisement.serviceUuids)
....
```

4. **Connect to the car (device.js)**

```
connect() {
    try {
        const that = this
        console.log('Connecting with ' + this.id)
        const getService = function(services){
            if (os.platform() === 'win32' || os.platform() === 'linux') {
                return services[2]
            } else {
                return service[0] // macOS
            }
        }

        const setCharacteristics = function(characteristics) {
            for(let i in characteristics) {
                const characteristic = characteristics[i]
                if (characteristic.uuid == 'be15bee06186407e83810bd89c4d8df4') {
                    that.readCharacteristic = characteristic
                }

                if (characteristic.uuid == 'be15bee16186407e83810bd89c4d8df4') {
                    that.writeCharacteristic = characteristic
                } 
            }                
        }

        const onConnect = async function() {
            const services = await that.peripheral.discoverServices([])
            const service = await getService(services)
            const characteristics = await service.discoverCharacteristics([])
            await setCharacteristics(characteristics)
            // Listen to own disconnect
            that.peripheral.once('disconnect', () => {
                mediator.private.emit('deviceDisconnected', this)
            })
            mediator.private.emit('deviceConnected', that)
        }

        this.peripheral.once('connect', onConnect)
        this.peripheral.connect()
    } catch(err) {
        throw new Error(err)
    }
}
```

4. **THEN: Activate SDK Mode (device.js)**

```
activateSDKMode() {
    console.log('Activating SDKMode for ' + this.id)
    const that = this
    if(!this.isConnected) {
        return new Error('Car is not connected yet.')
    }
    const message = coder.encodeSDKActivation()
    this._writeMessage(message)
    .then(() => {
        mediator.private.emit('SDKModeOn', that)
    })
}
```

5. **THEN: Turn on Logging (device.js)**

```
turnOnLogging() {
    console.log('Turning logging on for ' + this.id)
    let that = this
    if(!that.isConnected) {
        return new Error('Car is not connected yet.')
    }

    that.readCharacteristic.notify(true)
    that.readCharacteristic.on('read', (data) => {
        that._onMessage(data)
    })
    mediator.private.emit('loggingOn', that)
}
```

[1] https://github.com/steinroe/anki-overdrive-sdk